# 'translate3d' strange rendering on chome /makes fonts look different

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, leaflet, translate3d

I'm having a leaflet map which uses `-webkit-transform: translate3d`.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="foo">some text</div>
```

Let's say we have the above code and `foo` is located over the `map`. `foo` and all items over the `map` (and its margins) are somewhat losing their original view. For example the text becomes slightly different. If there is a div with a border over `map` the left border might sometimes (!?) be lost.

This bug is generated on my OS X chrome. Safari seems to render it fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` on the html tag and now seems to have been solved.